# Lua Unknown error when typing something in Zerobrane studio IDE

Tags: lua

What is this weird error that I am getting when I typing something in the Zerobrane studio IDE? It crashes my IDE. But The game project compiles and runs fine.

When I turn off "Autocomplete Identifiers" from Edit menu, then the error doesn't come up.

Also, I searched entire google and facebook for some help or solution but no luck at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the autocomplete logic in the IDE, which has been [fixed in the repository](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/837).

Comment: Yes, I have opened the ticket